# RecyclerView to ViewPager Transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, master-detail, android-transitions

I have a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews`, and when I click on a `CardView` I open a new Activity with a `ViewPager` containing the details of that card.

**What I want to achieve** is this :

1) When I go from the list to the details Activity, I want to so with a **transition** where the shared element is the `CardView` clicked (a little bit like in the Gmail app).

2) When I go back from the details Activity (`ViewPager`) to the list, I want a transition where the current item goes to its place in the list (again like in Gmail app).

**What I did so far** :

- I enabled the enter and exit transitions in the `styles.xml`.
- I declared the shared element by declaring the `transitionName` in the XML (on both files : the list and the viewPager).

Here are some portions of my code :

Details Activity :

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.card_detail);
    mPagerAdapter = new DetailPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition); // to go the right position in the pager...
```

Adapter of the `RecyclerView` (where a start the Details Activity with a transition) :

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity, card, "card_transition_name");
mContext.startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

I left the default transition but it's a little weird : the transition is a combination of fade and change scale that is really messy...

Can somebody help me on how to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you have any look with this? I want to implement same behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I did it without a transition...

Comment: Too bad. I will keep looking for a solution.

Comment: what about this, make some customization: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html